# "Specified cast is not valid" error in C# windows forms program

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having a "Specified cast is not valid" error. Windows form application in C#. I'm trying to retrieve a value from a table. The value is either a smallint, or a numeric(i tried both fields, both give me the same error), and I try to store it in an int variable.

here's the source:

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) //"select * from table where fieldname = " + value
{

 while (rdr.Read())
 {
  int number = (int)rdr["quantity"]; // error is here
```

Comment: have you tried convert.toint16(rdr["quantity"];

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`rdr["quantity"]` is going to be a boxed something. If it is not an `int` then you can not unbox it directly to an `int` (which is what you are trying to do) as you have to first unbox it to the appropriate type (say, `short`). But this is too cumbersome so for clarity you're better off saying

```
Convert.ToInt32(rdr["quantity"]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  if(rdr["quantity"].GetType() != typeof(int))
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
      "quantity is a " + rdr["quantity"].GetType());
  int number = (int)rdr["quantity"]; // error is here
```

Comment: I don't see how this assigns the quantity in number variable. logically, I should still get an error, if i'm right

Comment: @jello It'll throw an exception that tells you excatly what type rdr["quantity"] is.  Without knowing this, all these answers are pissing in the wind.  For all we know "quantity" is a friggen byte array.  Put it in your code and run it.

Comment: BTW, when I say "run it" I don't mean run it in release mode.  Run it in debug mode from visual studio.

Comment: i see. well, in this case, I created the database, so I know what datatype the fields are

Comment: @jello yes, you may know the data types in the database, but you *obviously* don't know what the .NET equivalent type is, or its DBNULL, hence the "specified cast is invalid" message.

Answer (score 2):

Silly suggestion, maybe - but have you considered trying this - grab the result from your `SqlDataReader` as an instance of `object` and then checking what type it is? No one can tell you better what it *really* is than the CLR type system! :-)

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        object obj = rdr["quantity"];

        if(obj != null)
        {
            string objType = obj.GetType().FullName;
        }
    }
 }
```

If you do get a value back, you can check what type it is and hopefully convert it accordingly, depending on your results.

Answer (score 1):

I bet `quantity` is `NULL`, which is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the two options.

```
int number = rdr.getInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("quantity"));
```

or

```
int number = int.parse(rdr["quantity"].ToString());
```

Comment: The first option is not a valid overload, the second won't compile.

Comment: Oops, fixed my topos, was writing from memory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
int number=convert.toint16(rdr["quantity"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you know what the value should be because you created the database... Can you check that rdr["quantity"] has a value then run a try parse on it?

```
if(rdr["quantity"] != null) {
    int? number = null;
    if(int.TryParse(rdr["quantity"].ToString(), out number)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hurray, I have an int. Up vote Coov!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sl_id = Convert.ToInt32(lblintroducerid.Text.ToString());
 sl_rank = Convert.ToInt32(lblassorank.Text.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using SqlDataReader's GetInt32()

```
rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("quantity"));
```